# How would I prevent a wild Pokemon from fleeing?

Tags: pokemon-series

In my adventuring in Pokemon White, I have come to the attempt to catch Thundurus. However, I can't seem to make a move without it fleeing on the next turn.

I realize already that there are ways to stop this... For instance, I had the option to teach Mean Look to my Cofagrigus, but I absentmindedly passed it up (I'm out of Heart Scales, and therefore can't get it back...). Additionally, I don't have any Pokemon with the Arena Trap, Shadow Tag, or Magnet Pull abilities.

Are there any other methods of preventing the wild Pokemon's escape?

(Granted, I have the Master Ball, but I'd prefer not to use it.)

Comment: Does Thundurus flee on the very first turn, or after you manage to get an attack in?

Comment: I have a single chance to make a move, which after my unsuccess it flees.

Comment: Do you mean it doesn't attack, but flees on its turn? Or after it attacks?

Comment: Oh, yes, it flees just as its turn begins. It doesn't attack.

Comment: You can get more heart scales from wild luvdisc. Heck, heart scales are basically luvdisc's whole purpose in the games.

Comment: I actually didn't know that, but I'll employ it soon. Thanks for the info.

Comment: if you have a pokemon with good agility it may be possible to put it to sleep and hope you can do whatever it takes to make the catch before it wakes up...

Comment: @Firobug They... still escape even when asleep. as broken and derpy as that is, a sleeping entei still runs from the trainer!

Comment: im sry... this is why I love my dual flash carts and ds' with a save state option...just trade with someone for them and save then trade back for a ratta and reload state.....thats the best exploit ive found with the hard ones shy of actually cheating or hacking the game....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'll quickly go over the options you already mentioned before listing everything else.

The simplest way would be to teach your Cofagrigus [Mean Look](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Mean_Look_(move)) again, by simply fishing wild [Luvdisc](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Luvdisc_(Pok%C3%A9mon)), which have a [50% chance of holding a Heart Scale](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Luvdisc_(Pok%C3%A9mon)#Held_items), and using any move that lets you take their item, like [Thief](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Thief_(move)), [Covet](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Covet_(move)), [Switcheroo](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Switcheroo_(move)), and [Trick](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Trick_(move)). Failing that, you can catch them, take the Heart Scale, and release them.

About the abilities you mention, only [Shadow Tag](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Shadow_Tag_(Ability)) would work out of them, since Thundurus' Flying-type makes it immune to [Arena Trap](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Arena_Trap_(Ability)), and it can't be trapped by [Magnet Pull](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Magnet_Pull_(Ability)) as it is not a Steel-type.

Luckily, there's a number of other moves that either permanently or temporarily trap a Pokémon.

- [Spider Web](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Spider_Web_(move)) works exactly like Mean Look, and will keep Thundurus trapped as long as you don't switch out the Pokémon that used Spider Web (unless you [Baton Pass](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Baton_Pass_(move)) out, but that's getting sidetracked).
- Moves that deal damage over time like [Wrap](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Wrap_(move)) will also trap the Pokémon for as long as the move lasts. Since Thundurus flees when it attempts to make a move, and the effect of these moves ends at the end of a turn, it is possible to keep Thundurus trapped indefinitely by using one of those moves again after the effect fades. The full list of damage over time moves is: [Bind](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Bind_(move)), [Clamp](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Clamp_(move)), [Fire Spin](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Fire_Spin_(move)), [Magma Storm](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Magma_Storm_(move)), [Sand Tomb](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Sand_Tomb_(move)) (which won't hit Thundurus unless [Gravity](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Gravity_(move)) or [Smack Down](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Smack_Down_(move)) has been used), [Whirlpool](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Whirlpool_(move)), and Wrap. [Infestation](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Infestation_(move)) is another move, but it was introduced in [Generation VI](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Generation_VI). Keep in mind that these moves deal damage each turn, and as such will kill a low health Thundurus if you don't manage to catch it quickly.

I'd suggest Shadow Tag, Mean Look, or Spider Web since your goal is to catch Thundurus, and not to make it faint. Additionally, many Pokémon that can learn the aforementioned moves or can possess the aforementioned abilities can also learn status moves such as [Hypnosis](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Hypnosis_(move)), which will make catching Thundurus easier.

Comment: This has been very informative, for which I thank you. I'll have it caught in no time at all.